# Freeing the buffer of a blocked stream in C

Tags: c, multithreading, stream, buffer

In a multithreaded application I need to cancel threads. Some of them use the `flockfile`
 mechanism which apparently is not a valid cancellation point for `pthread_cancel`. I managed to kill the threads by sending a `SIGUSR1` signal using `pthread_kill`, forcing them to `pthread_exit` in the signal handler. Cleaning up the allocated memory proved to be simple in my case (it's all on the stack), but I can't, of course, close the file streams. Is there any way of freeing the buffers or removing the locks? On my system each of the unclosed buffers hogs 16KB of memory which accumulates quickly.

Comment: it's only a workaround, but there is `ftrylockfile`.

Comment: well there's a 're-engineer-around' with `lockf`, but...

Comment: I tried `ftrylockfile` but this only helps if the thread has not already acquired the lock. Sometimes it will catch the thread in the middle of the locked passage and it's the same problem again. Hmm, lockf seems to be implemented on process level?

Comment: What do you mean "on process level"? On linux, lockf is implemented via fcntl(F_SETLKW). It's not done in userspace and it's not a process-private lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of force-killing the threads, you should communicate them a "finish" message, then the thread can clean up after itself before exiting clean.

You are already doing the messageing part with SIGUSR1, so you will need to kepp track of open handles so you can unlock/free any in-use ones from the signal handler

Comment: I have the file handles, but you can't unlock them from another thread other than the one just killed. There is no information in the signal handler which would allow the signaled thread do something about it.

Comment: Unless the signaled thread is blocked, you can send it a message (keep track of what threads "own" your locked resources) to unlock the resource.  If the thread is blocked, you should change the blocking mechanism used to allow interruption (e.g. block for a specific time only then check if it needs to exit, and block again if it does not)

Comment: Yes, it is blocked, very likely even. The blocking call is a getc_unlocked call on the stream. Is there a non blocking version of getc, I could not find it?

Comment: from the [manual](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/getc_unlocked.3.asp) if you use non-blocking sockets you can re-try if there is nothing to read at the moment (return value: EWOULDBLOCK): sleep, check for exit condition and try to read again

Comment: You can use [fcntl](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/fcntl.3.asp) to open the file in non-blocking mode